# Reload a new BoM in a manufacturing order

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

In odoo V13, we need to "update" the BoM in a manufacturing order. We use the PLM application to make changes to BoMs, and a change was made *after* the manufacturing order was created. We would prefer to not delete and re-create the manufacturing order.

I came across [this post](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/is-there-a-way-to-reload-the-bom-into-draft-manufacturing-orders-189656) but there are no instructions for Odoo V13. I tried to figure it out by trial and error but I don't know odoo enough to be certain the result is correct.

This is the code for V14 with functions unavailable in V13 identified:

```
for record in records:
  record._compute_allowed_product_ids() <- Not in V13
  record._onchange_bom_id()
  record._onchange_move_raw()
  record._onchange_move_finished() <- Not in V13
  record._onchange_location
```

I planned on adapting it to work with a wizard to allow selecting a specific BoM version.

How can I create a server action to "update/change" the BoM of a manufacturing order?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it fully but played around with it on an odoo 13 runbot instance.

```py
# only change draft manufacturing orders
for record in records.filtered(lambda r: r.state == 'draft'):
    # trigger changing to the same product
    record.onchange_product_id()
    # trigger bom change from product onchange
    record._onchange_bom_id()
    # trigger raw materials moves change after bom change
    record._onchange_move_raw()
    # trigger some other changes which usually are done anyways
    record.onchange_picking_type()
    record._onchange_date_planned_start()
    record._onchange_location()
    # finally set procurement group again, which is usually done in create()
    record.move_raw_ids.write({
        'group_id': record.procurement_group_id.id,
        'reference': record.name,
    })
```

It will be much more difficult to change BoMs on confirmed manufacturing orders, so this solution only works for draft orders.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately i would need it to work on confirmed MOs as well...